# "About" page in iOS app has no "menu" button, so you can't escape it easily

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

This bug is simple, yet pretty annoying.

Basically, when you go to the about page, the sidebar button is gone, and you get imprisoned there. You have to click "inbox", "achievements", or exit the app to escape from it.

[image: !]

Is this possible to be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a stupid mistake on my part.  I had logic that if the screen wasn't displayed as a popup it should remove the left item (which on a popup is "Done").  This of course is completely unnecessary over engineering and wiped out the menu button.  I'll be pushing out a build today with the fix.

For what it's worth here are a few ways to get out of there if it happens again:

- You can swipe the navigation bar to the right to reveal the menu.
- After killing the app you can get back to the feed by going into Settings.app, finding "Stack Exchange" and turning on "Return to feed" under "Crash Recovery".
- You can also clear the saved app state by pressing the home button once to get to springboard then tapping twice to get to the app switcher and swiping up on the app.  Just tapping twice in the app and swiping up won't work as the app's state will be saved.